# SQL Query to Linq To Entities

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Linq To Entities and I have difficulties to translate a SQL query to Linq.

Here is my query in SQL :

```
SELECT row FROM table
WHERE row not between 'A' and 'Z' 
and NOT REGEXP_LIKE(row,'[[:digit:]]{3}')
```

Actually my row is a varchar and I want the query to return items that are not single uppercase letter or 3 characters number (only "A" or "123").

Answer (score 0):

```
from row in table
where !RegEx.Match(row, "^([A-Z]|[0-9]{3})$").Success
select row
```

Comment: Regex is not supported by Linq To Entities. But it works if I convert my query in IEnumerable as below : 

    var query = from item in Db.Table.AsEnumerable()
                where !Regex.Match(item.row, "^([A-Z]|[0-9 {3})$").Success
                select item.row;

I've found another solution without converting to IEnumerable but it's much longer.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about non-regex-support in LinqToEntities. I know well Linq but only a very little about LinqToEntities.